# Is downloading a file to a cloud instance ingress, or egress?

Tags: cloud

I'm investigating cloud computing solutions, and I'm not 100% sure about ingress vs. egress.

I understand that ingress is data that comes IN to your instance (for example if a user sends a request to your site or uploads a file to your instance), and that egress is data that LEAVES your instance (e.g. if you return a file in response to a user request).

But let's say I have a script running on my instance that downloads a 1gb file. Logic tells me that's a small egress (to request the file), then a large ingress (the file itself), but I'm also wondering if that might somehow be counted as egress due to it being the response to an egress.

Which would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm also wondering if that might somehow be counted as egress due to it being the response to an egress.

For usage metrics the reason for the traffic is irrelevant, it doesn't matter if the packet is a "request", a "response" or something else.

Usage metrics are really simple, they are the sum (over a specific period) of the size of all IP datagram packets sent and received by your instance:

- All packets with the IP-address of your instance as the source are egress.
- All packets with the IP-address of your instance as the destination are ingress.

Some providers may distinguish classes of traffic based on the sources/destinations of the packets, for instance when traffic between instances and/or other services offered by the same provider won't be charged (at the same level).

Comment: I thought it was that simple, but wanted to confirm. Thanks!